# Where in the registry can I find the definitions of icons in the notification area?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-registry, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where are the items in the system tray stored?](https://superuser.com/questions/56155/where-are-the-items-in-the-system-tray-stored)

Where in the registry can I find the definitions of icons in the notification area? I want to start removing icons I hate, like Adobe Reader's etc.

Comment: True. It is a duplicate. Search didn't find the other question when I looked. Apparently running programs can display icons in the notification area. I will hunt down autostart programs in the registry.

Comment: Found the thing. It hid in a Wow64 node of the registry! Why do all programs think that I want them running in the background all day???

Answer (score 1):

Notification icons are *not* kept in the registry. They are added dynamically, by programs that are running at that moment. In other words, you have to configure the programs themselves to stop polluting the notification area.

- If you have an "Adobe Reader update" icon there, ***update the damn thing*** and it will go away. (This applies equally to all "update available" icons. They are there for a good reason.)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference:

Icons in the notification area are displayed by programs running, usually in the background. Those programs are often started by Run entries in the registry.

Look here:

\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

And here:

\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

In the HKey_Current_User and HKey_Local_Machine hives.

Comment: Start > Run > msconfig > startup